# auto zoom/center google maps api?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I am pretty experienced when it come to php mysql, but javascript has got me scratching my head. I am trying to add google maps to my website to show where picture in my database were taken. I got the static google map to work, but it will only display 37 markers due to the url character limitations. I followed the tutorial at google maps api docs, and i have a map that will display all the coordinates for the images in my database. My problem is that i cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the map to auto center and auto zoom to fit all of my markers. my test website for my map is at [maptest](http://www.perfectpanorama.com/maptest/phpsqlajax_map_v3.html). I found this [tutorial](http://www.wiliam.com.au/wiliam-blog/google-maps-auto-zoom-centre-your-map) on how to auto center/zoom my map by no matter where i put his code i get errors. this is the code i have for my map that does not auto zoom/center:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Google Maps AJAX + mySQL/PHP Example</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?             key=AIzaSyDnMkDkoCHNE7BG4eobjeMJdWWZtdZvzeg&sensor=false"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

  var customIcons = {
  restaurant: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
    shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  },
  bar: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
    shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  }
};

function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.293564,-39.07617),
    zoom: 2,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml3.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      //var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      //var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>";
      //var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        //icon: icon.icon,
        //shadow: icon.shadow
      });

      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  });
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}

   //]]>
  </script>
 </head>

  <body onload="load()">
   <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
    </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Tried this?

```
var fitToMarkers = function(markers) {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var length = markers.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng));
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have not tried that. Can i put var fitToMarkers where it says center? Like this:                                function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: fitToMarkers,
        zoom: 2,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
     
    var fitToMarkers = function(markers) {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var length = markers.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng));
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
};